# Sorting numbers in python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to get a function where if you do sort(listname) it would sort all the numbers inside that list from least to greatest.

I'm not sure whats wrong with mine, but I need some help as the output isn't actually least to greatest it does least to greatest for the first two numbers of the number.

**Example :**

> If list has 23, 212, 44 in it than I sort it the output will be like this.

**Output :**

> 212,23,44

It **should be** 23, 44, 212.

**Code:**

```
def sort(my_list):
    size = len(my_list)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size-i-1):
            if(my_list[j] > my_list[j+1]):
                tmp = my_list[j]
                my_list[j] = my_list[j+1]
                my_list[j+1] = tmp
```

**More code :**

```
numbers=([])
amount=input("How many numbers are in your list? ")
print("")
counter = 0
ran = 0
while counter < int(amount):
    counter = counter + 1
    ran = ran + 1
    num3 = input(str(ran) + ". Input: ")
    try:
       val = int(num3)
    except ValueError:
       num3 = input(str(ran) + ". Input: ")
    sort(numbers)
    numbers.append(num3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like your list doesn't contain any numbers but strings. Python doesn't try to guess what might be inside of those strings, so you get an odd sort order.

You have two options:

1. Convert list elements to `int` before comparing them (`if(int(my_list[j]) > int(my_list[j+1])):`)
2. Search this site for `python natural sort` to get answers how to implement "natural sorting" in Python.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want it sorted, use sorted:

```
sorted_my_list = sorted(my_list,key=int)
```

Or to sort it, in place, use

```
my_list.sort(key=int)
```

If you want to fix your program, turn my_list into ints or at least compare integers

```
if ( int(my_list[j]) > int(my_list[j+1])):
```

Also, you can swap two variables in one statement:

```
my_list[j],my_list[j+1] = my_list[j+1],my_list[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used your code (Just added a `return` statement). And it returns the expected values:

```
def sort(my_list):
    size = len(my_list)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size-i-1):
            if(my_list[j] > my_list[j+1]):
                tmp = my_list[j]
                my_list[j] = my_list[j+1]
                my_list[j+1] = tmp
    return my_list # Note I added this return statement

print sort([23,212,44])
>>> 
[23, 44, 212]
```

Comment: I get this: 212,23,44... Weird.